# Angular 2; How to hide/disable the past events in fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using [full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

```
this.calendarOptions = {
            height: '1000',
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            header:
            {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,listYear',
            },
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            editable: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm A',
            eventLimit: true,


            events: (start, end, title, callback) => {
                this.calenderservice.getExamCandidateById(this.value)
                    .subscribe(response => {
                        callback(response),
                            this.modalData = response.Items
                        this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.modalData)
                        console.log(this.modalData);
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            },
```

response

```
 Items:{
    ExamName:null
    ExamSiteId:334
    Id:85
    LastUpdateDateTime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    PostalCode:"33172"
    PptSeats:null
    SeatCount:0
    SiteName:"UF"
    State:"FL"
    end:"2017-09-27T10:30:00"
    isCbt:"1"
    isPpt:null
    start:"2017-09-27T10:30:00"
    title:"7 available"
}
```

From above code i am getting all start and end dates from response,and displays the events in calendar

i want to hide the past events,how i can hide the events which contain past start and end dates from current date in fullcalendar.

please help me.

Comment: Maybe don't return them from the server in the first place? You can maybe send a flag variable to the server if need be, to indicate that you want it not to give you events before the current date. At the moment you don't even seem to be sending it the start/end dates that fullCalendar gives you, so I guess you are pointlessly returning _all_ your events even when fullCalendar won't display them.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply filter before passing the value to full calendar. Something like this:

```
 events: (start, end, title, callback) => {
            this.calenderservice.getExamCandidateById(this.value)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    callback(response),
                     var date = new Date(); //Today's date
                    this.modalData = response.Items.filter( item => item.StartDate > date || item.EndDate > date  ); //only select items whose start or end date are after today's date.
                    this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.modalData)
                    console.log(this.modalData);
                    console.log(response);
                });
```

Comment: Thank you,`this.modalData = response.Items.filter(items => items.start > date || items.end > date);` i added, but getting modalData empty array,

Comment: can you do `console.log(response);` and add in the question.

Comment: i added response to my question.

Comment: only one item @PramodRamadand ?